# How to Update populated feilds in MOngoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

Let Say i am populating Contestants with their respective  Wallets like this

```
let contestant = await User.findById(playerId).populate({
      path: "Wallet",
    });
```

Now I am updating the wallet cash like this

```
 contestant.Wallet.cash -= Matchcontest.joiningfee;
await contestant.save()
```

after doing this the Wallet cash is not updating in MongoDB am i doing something wrong or we cannot update the populated values

I tried doing the code above but not able to solve it

Comment: You should try to retrieve the `Wallet`s for the specified `playerId` and update those directly using [updateMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.updateMany()).

Comment: Did you try saving the wallet, like `contestant.Wallet.save()`?